# Unity.Resolve for a class with a dependency injection

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, unity-container

I am using Unity to control Dependency Injection in my Xamarin Forms application.  I have a view model class that takes a parent id and a unity injected service as constructor parameters.

```
public class BrowseViewModel {
    public BrowseViewModel(int parentId, IInjectedService injectedService) {
    }
}
```

I have registered the class in the unity container.

```
unityContainer.registerType<BrowseViewModel>();
```

I have also registered the service in the unity container.

```
unityContainer.registerType<IInjectedService, InjectedService>();
```

My question is, how do I specify the value for `parentId` when Unity creates an instance of my class?  I don't think I should have to specify the `injectedService` parameter because I have already registered this class with unity and it is a singleton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register `BrowseViewModel` like that:

```
container.RegisterType<Func<int, BrowseViewModel>>(
                new InjectionFactory(c =>
                    new Func<int, BrowseViewModel>(id=> c.Resolve<BrowseViewModel>(new ParameterOverrides { { "parentId", id},))));
```

Then in contrutor where you use BrowseViewModel, you need to use `Func<int, BrowseViewModel> browseViewMdoelFactory`
and use it like that:

```
class SomeViewClass
{
    SomeViewClass(Func<int, BrowseViewModel> browseViewMdoelFactory)
    {    
    browsceViewModelFactory(parentId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options. You can register your BrowserViewModel like this:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<BrowseViewModel>(new InjectionFactory(c => new BrowseViewModel(1234, c.Resolve<IInjectedService>())));
```

But this way you have a fixed value for `parentId` (1234 in this example).

You could also use a factory design pattern like so:

```
public class BrowseViewModelFactory
{
    private IInjectedService _injectedService;
    public BrowseViewModelFactory(IInjectedService injectedService)
    {
        _injectedService = injectedService;
    }
    public BrowseViewModel CreateBrowseViewModel(int parentId)
    {
        return new BrowseViewModel(parentId, _injectedService);
    }
}
```

Then you inject the `BrowseViewModelFactory` in class you need the `BrowseViewModel` and call the create method with the correct `parentId`. Like:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private BrowseViewModelFactory _browseViewModelFactory;
    public SomeOtherClass(BrowseViewModelFactory browseViewModelFactory)
    {
        _browseViewModelFactory = browseViewModelFactory;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var browseViewModel = _browseViewModelFactory.CreateBrowseViewModel(4321);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can set the `parentId` when you try to resolve `BrowserViewModel`.

At first, just register type:

```
        container.RegisterType<BrowseViewModel>();
        // Mark that InjectedService is the singleton using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager
        container.RegisterType<IInjectedService, InjectedService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And then resolve type. For this you need to override all primitive types in constructor when try to resolve a type, so you can use `ParameterOverrides` as pointed out in the answer by @Crekate or can directly put `params ParameterOverride` as in the code below:

```
        var vm = container.Resolve<BrowseViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("parentId", 546));
```